# Java RMI doenst "go to" function of interface

Tags: java, rmi

Hello I am trying to create an RMI programm that sends and receives data from a server. However after I create my registries and look them up etc, and point my program to a method in the interface it throws itself into an integerpage (via debugger). my code is as follows

#### For the client

```
public static void SendData(int score,String name) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
    try {
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",1099);
            TestRemote remote =  (TestRemote) reg.lookup("TestRMI"); 
            remote.SendMyData(score,name);           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String ex = e.toString();
        }
```

#### For the server

```
public class RMIserver {
    public static void main(String[] args ) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException {
        RemoteImp imp = new RemoteImp();
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        reg.rebind("TestRMI", imp);
        System.out.println("Server is Started");        
    }
}
```

#### Interface

```
public interface TestRemote extends Remote {

    public ArrayList<TempPlayer> getOpdata() throws RemoteException;
    public void SendMyData(int score, String player) throws RemoteException;}
```

And for the interface implementation:

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<TempPlayer> opdata = new ArrayList<TempPlayer>();
    private ArrayList<String> lobbydata = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected RemoteImp() throws RemoteException
    {

    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<TempPlayer> getOpdata() throws RemoteException {
        return  opdata;
    }

    @Override
    public void SendMyData(int score, String name) throws RemoteException {
        //opdata.add(String.valueOf(score));

        for (TempPlayer player : opdata) {
            if (player.player == name) {
                player.setScore(score);
            } else {
                opdata.add(new TempPlayer(score, name));
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to invoke `SendData` by calling `Remote.senddata`, it goes to the Integer.java page. My question now is what could cause this and how do I get the program to actually go to the function I want it to go to?

Comment: have you tried without the debugger? also, in the first code snippet you does not print the exception so how you can be sure that one was not raised?

Comment: When you are using rmi that means you have java processes which act using rmi proxy object. in your implementation SendMyData method does not return anything

Comment: When i add a return (boolean) to my Sendata method it now throws the program into eventdispatchthread. And as i previously had it function while using debugger (yesterday) i am certain that the debbugger is not the problem.

Comment: 'Throws the program into event dispatch thread' is meaningless, as are all the other symptoms you have described. You are getting *exceptions,* and you need to include the corresponding stack traces in your question.